# Is possible random number on html5?

Tags: html, variables, random

I am create pure html5 page now.
I always need clear CSS and Javascript cache from browser setting.
Is possible load CSS and JavaScript with random number for files version parament ?

Like `<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/desktop.css?v=*HERE_I_NEED_RANDOR_NUMBER*">`

Comment: The answer is no. But you can use Javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thats impossible with only HTML. HTML is markup language

Way to do this with Javascript

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100001);
var newCSS = document.createElement("link");

newCSS.rel = "stylesheet";
newCSS.type = "text/css";
newCSS.href = `css/desktop.css?v=${randomNumber}`;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newCSS)
```

Comment: is possible using javascript ?